# Lightning Dashboard

Tags: lightning, reporting, dashboard, help, helptext

Is it possible in Lightning dashboards to have a little circled I or similar feature that provides more information about what the report is displaying? I know you can have a similar feature on fields in the page layout but I would like to add this so I can further explain why a rep might appear to be under performing because they are performing their work flow wrong and provide suggestions in how to improve the calculations on the dashboards.

Comment: Not really. You can add a subtitle, but that's really just a subtitle. There's no way to add an informational section to the dashboard. Perhaps you'll want to [make an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch)?

Comment: @BarelyPerry Please refer this link sure your getting some data about lightning dashboards.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_implementation_reports_dashboards